# std::filesystem link error on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, c++17

I learning usage of C++ filesystem library (`std::filesystem`). The following code cause linker error.

How I can fix it?

Code for `fs.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using namespace std::filesystem;

    directory_iterator iter{"."};
    for (auto& ent: iter) {
        std::cout << ent.path() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc7vhf9X.o: in function `main':
fs.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator*() const'
/usr/bin/ld: fs.cpp:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator++()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc7vhf9X.o: in function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)':
fs.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx1118directory_iteratorC2ERKNS0_4pathE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx1118directory_iteratorC5ERKNS0_4pathE]+0x26): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path
const&, std::filesystem::directory_options, std::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc7vhf9X.o: in function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path<char [2], std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>(char const (&) [2], std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
fs.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC2IA2_cS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC5IA2_cS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE]+0x6d): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.10
- g++ 8.2.0
- compile options: `g++ -std=c++17 -o fs fs.cpp`

Comment: As this duplicate has libstdc++ and libc++ answers.

Comment: GCC 8 still needs `-lstdc++fs`

Comment: They will probably require it until C++20.

Answer (score 27):

It need to add `-lstdc++fs` to option.

```
g++ -lstdc++fs -std=c++17 -o fs fs.cpp -lstdc++fs
```