# Linking to std++fs - what syntax to choose

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, compiler-errors

### Context

I initially developed a C++17 code with `gcc 9.2`, but had to compile it on a system that has only `gcc 8.2` available.

I had the linking error:

```
CMakeFiles/qegg1.dir/qegg1.cpp.o: In function `std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)':
qegg1.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem6existsERKNS_7__cxx114pathE[_ZNSt10filesystem6existsERKNS_7__cxx114pathE]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::status(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&)'
CMakeFiles/qegg1.dir/qegg1.cpp.o: In function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
qegg1.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC5INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE]+0x64): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
```

### Solution

The solution to this error is explained in these posts:

- [std::filesystem link error on ubuntu 18.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852684/stdfilesystem-link-error-on-ubuntu-18-10/53852988)
- [Link errors using <filesystem> members in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729328/link-errors-using-filesystem-members-in-c17)
- [Undefined reference error with new filesystem library and clang++7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807011/undefined-reference-error-with-new-filesystem-library-and-clang7)

Following the answers in these posts (in short, `gcc 8.2` needs an explicit link to filesystem), I updated my CMakeLists by linking explicitely to `stdc++fs`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# find some dependencies ...
add_executable(myprog myprog.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myprog LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} stdc++fs)
```

It compile fine on my local system (gcc 9.2) and on the remote (gcc 8.2), but I don't understand why.

### Question:

How compatible is this syntax with later versions of gcc and how does it compare to the solution describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729328/link-errors-using-filesystem-members-in-c17) to write:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lstdc++fs -std=c++17")
```

Comment: Putting option `-l` into the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is never a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev ! It confirms what i remembered from my old lectures on cmake (more or less setting flags should raise interrogations). But still, how is it that specifying the `stdc++fs` option when gcc >= 9.2 does not trigger warnings or errors ?

Comment: Previously, the filesystem part of the standard library wasn't included in `libstdc++` but was only available by explicitly linking with `libstdc++fs`. `g++` is still shipped with `libstdc++fs` so explicitly linking with it isn't a problem even for newer `g++` versions.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation, thank you !

Comment: Can i summarize your comment in an answer so i can close the question ? :)

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler :-) Ok, done! I really wanted to be able to provide an even cleaner way of specifying the library dependency using CMake, but I couldn't find it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, the filesystem part of the standard library wasn't included in `libstdc++` but was only available by explicitly linking with `libstdc++fs`. `g++` is still shipped with `libstdc++fs` so explicitly linking with it isn't a problem even for newer `g++` versions.

---

<sub>I was hoping to find a clean [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) way of doing `find_package` similar to that of when using threads</sub>

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(application PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

<sub>but unfortunately, I only found how to do that for `Boost::filesystem`...</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer! On a side note, how do you justify using PRIVATE for threads and does it means that ```libstdc++fs``` should also be declared private?

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler You're welcome! I think I read [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html) and decided it was a good idea. I'm not that good with CMake though.